# Attendance Reversing results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im having the problems taking attendance using 3 radio buttons(Present,Absent,Late), when submitting the results in database are being saved in a reversed manner.
But for other fields datas are being recorded successfully: i have deep searched and found how in can handle using a forach loop but on the other side its reversing other fields also:

Below is my code.

```
<tbody>

<?php

$counter=0;

$qry_std_by_class="select 
        student_class_tbl.student_REG_number,
        student_tbl.first_name as fn,
        student_tbl.lastname,
        accademic_year.year_name 
    FROM student_class_tbl 
    INNER JOIN classes_tbl 
        on student_class_tbl.class_ID=classes_tbl.class_ID 
    INNER JOIN student_tbl 
        on student_class_tbl.student_REG_number=student_tbl.student_REG_number 
    INNER JOIN accademic_year 
        on student_class_tbl.accedemic_id=accademic_year.accademic_year_ID";

$query = $dbh->prepare($qry_std_by_class);    
$query->execute();

$rslts = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    foreach($rslts as $rslt)
    {                           
        $regnumber=$rslt->student_REG_number;
        $fname=decrypt($rslt->fn,$key);
        $lname=decrypt($rslt->lastname,$key);
        $academic=$rslt->year_name;       
        ?>                

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $regnumber ?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $regnumber; ?>" name="reg_number[]">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($fname)?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($fname); ?>" name="first_name[]">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($lname)?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lname); ?>" name="last_name[]">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($academic)?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($academic); ?>" name="academic[]">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $regnumber ?></td>
            <td class="attend-record">
                <div class="form-group">                            
                    <input type="radio"  name="attendance_status[<?php echo htmlentities($counter) ?>]" value="1" ><label for="present">Present</label>

                    <input type="radio"  name="attendance_status[<?php echo htmlentities($counter) ?>]" value="0">Absent

                    <input type="radio"  name="attendance_status[<?php echo htmlentities($counter) ?>]" value="2" >Late 
                </div>
            </td> 
        </tr>

        <?php
        $counter++;
    }        
}     
?>

</tbody>
```

And this is the second portion of code for data peocessing:

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit_attendance']))
{
    $on_date = date('y-m-d');
    $time = date("H:i:s");
    $teacherID = $_SESSION['t_id'];
    $school_code = $_SESSION['skl_code'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');

    foreach($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id=>$attendance_status) {
        // $countrgs=count($_POST['reg_number']);
        //                      
        // for($i=0; $i < $countrgs; $i++) {

        $student_REG_number = $_POST['reg_number'][$id];
        $names = $_POST['first_name'][$id];                           
        $attendance_status = $_POST['attendance_status'][$id];

        $qry_insert_atte = "INSERT INTO attendance_tbl (
                student_REG_number, 
                names, 
                on_date, 
                school_code, 
                state, 
                teacher_ID, 
                time
            ) VALUES (
                :student_REG_number, 
                :names, 
                :on_date, 
                :school_code, 
                :attendance_status, 
                :teacherID, 
                :time
            )";

        $qry = $dbh->prepare($qry_insert_atte);

        $qry->bindParam(':student_REG_number',$student_REG_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':names',$names, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':on_date',$on_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':school_code',$school_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':attendance_status',$attendance_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':teacherID',$teacherID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $qry->bindParam(':time',$time, PDO::PARAM_STR);             

        $qry->execute();

        $mssg="<div class='alert alert-success col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-xl-6'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> Attendance Saved!
            <a href='' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'  style='text-decoration:none;'>&times;</a>
        </div>";

       }
    }
}
?>
```

**Results during data submission**

[image: Results during data submission]

And here is my results found:

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by _"Reversing results"_? All you've posted is some code that inserts a new record and then you show us some records from PHPMyAdmin. We have _no idea_ what it suppose to look like. Btw, there's one `}` too many in the end of the second code block.

Comment: You should really supply the counter value to _specify_ the array index with your other input fields, too, not only for the radio buttons. My guess is that you have the data for different “records” intermixing here somehow, because you rely on automatic index creation in part, and explicitly specify it in other places. Try and keep that consistent.

Comment: reversing results that im saying is that for example instead of getting present,present,absent,late according to what i've chooses to it gives the false results as(Absent,present,present,late) whis is equal to (0,1,1,2) as my values to be stored in database whle i should get(1,1,0,2) as true results

Comment: yeaa. have got the  `}` was for the for loop.. for this case while replace the radio buttons by text boxes and type manually the values are being successfully saved according to my wish

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of the `accademic_year` table?

Comment: academic table records will be fetched later,,

Comment: My problem is fixed now thanks all for your contribution to my issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query i added order by student_class_tbl.student_REG_number ASC

```
 select 
    student_class_tbl.student_REG_number,
    student_tbl.first_name as fn,
    student_tbl.lastname,
    accademic_year.year_name 
FROM student_class_tbl 
INNER JOIN classes_tbl 
    on student_class_tbl.class_ID=classes_tbl.class_ID 
INNER JOIN student_tbl 
    on student_class_tbl.student_REG_number=student_tbl.student_REG_number 
  INNER JOIN accademic_year 
    on student_class_tbl.accedemic_id=accademic_year.accademic_year_ID order by 
  student_class_tbl.student_REG_number ASC
```

Comment: OP has a problem _inserting_ data into the database from a form. What makes you think suggesting a _select_ query would improve anything here?

Comment: i thought maybe he is getting student registration number in wrong order that's why they are inserting in wrong pattern.

Comment: Thank you sir, my problem is fixed now, deeply appreciate!!